# How do I use Unity Web Requests for streaming audio... I want to use a cloud based TTS

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to use a cloud TTS within my Unity game.

With the newer versions (I am using 2019.1), they have deprecated WWW in favour of UnityWebRequest(s) within the API.

I have tried the [Unity Documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.UnityWebRequestMultimedia.GetAudioClip.html), but that didn't work for me.

I have also tried other threads and they use WWW which is deprecated for my Unity version.

```cs
    void Start()
    {
        StartCoroutine(PlayTTS());
    }

    IEnumerator PlayTTS()
    {
        using (UnityWebRequestMultimedia wr = new UnityWebRequestMultimedia.GetAudioClip(
            "https://example.com/tts?text=Sample%20Text&voice=Male",
            AudioType.OGGVORBIS)
        )

        {
            yield return wr.Send();

            if (wr.isNetworkError)
            {
                Debug.LogWarning(wr.error);
            }

            else
            {
                //AudioClip ttsClip = DownloadHandlerAudioClip.GetContent(wr);
            }
        }
    }
```

The URL in a browser (I used Firefox) successfully loaded the audio clip allowing me to play it.

What I want it to do is play the TTS when something happens in the game, it has been done within the "void Start" for testing purposes.

Where am I going wrong?

Thanks in advance

*Josh*

Answer (score 2):

[`UnityWebRequestMultimedia.GetAudioClip`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.UnityWebRequestMultimedia.GetAudioClip.html) automatically adds a default [`DownloadHandlerAudioClip`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.DownloadHandlerAudioClip.html) which has a property [`streamAudio`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.DownloadHandlerAudioClip-streamAudio.html).

Set this to true and add a check for [`UnityWebRequest.downloadedBytes`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.UnityWebRequest-downloadedBytes.html) in order to delay the playback before starting.

Something like

```
public AudioSource source;

IEnumerator PlayTTS()
{
    using (var wr = new UnityWebRequestMultimedia.GetAudioClip(
        "https://example.com/tts?text=Sample%20Text&voice=Male",
        AudioType.OGGVORBIS)
    )

    {
        ((DownloadHandlerAudioClip)wr.downloadHandler).streamAudio = true;

        wr.Send();

        while(!wr.isNetworkError && wr.downloadedBytes <= someThreshold)
        {
            yield return null;
        }

        if (wr.isNetworkError)
        {
            Debug.LogWarning(wr.error);
        }

        else
        {
            // Here I'm not sure if you would use
            source.PlayOneShot(DownloadHandlerAudioClip.GetContent(wr)); 
            // or rather
            source.PlayOneShot((DownloadHandlerAudioClip)wr.downloadHandler).audioClip);     
        }
    }
}
```

---

*Typed on smartphone so no warranty but I hope you get the idea*

Comment: This did not work, [here is a screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/txN3l43.png) I get red sqwiggleys and that.

Comment: Wait .. I just took it from your example ... what Unity versión do you use?

Comment: I'm using Unity 2019.1

Comment: Did you manage to get this working? I've also been trying to get audio streaming with no luck as of yet.