# UnityWebRequest does not complete

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am learning how to stream audio from an online source. My project is using UnityWebRequest and UnityWebRequestMultimedia to get an Audio stream. My Unity version is 2020.2.5f1.

The problem I am having is that the Web Request never completes. It reached about 98% progress and then restarts and I can't figure out why. The odd thing is that the URLs work in my browser but not in the Unity Editor. Here is my code:

```
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Networking;
using TMPro;

public class RadioManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public RadioStation[] radioStations = new RadioStation[0];
    public AudioSource source;

    public TextMeshProUGUI connectionStatus;
    public TextMeshProUGUI radioName;

    [System.Serializable]
    public class RadioStation
    {
        public string name;
        public string url;
    }


    private void Start()
    {
        StartCoroutine(DownloadAndPlay(radioStations[1]));
    }

    IEnumerator DownloadAndPlay(RadioStation radioStation)
    {
        radioName.text = radioStation.name;

        using (UnityWebRequest radioRequest = UnityWebRequestMultimedia.GetAudioClip(radioStation.url, AudioType.MPEG))
        {

            UnityWebRequestAsyncOperation _op = radioRequest.SendWebRequest();

            while(_op.progress < 1F)
            {
                Debug.Log($"Pending Request... {_op.progress}%");
                yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.25F);
            }

            if (radioRequest.result == UnityWebRequest.Result.ConnectionError)
            {
                connectionStatus.text = "Error Connecting!";
            }
            else if (radioRequest.result == UnityWebRequest.Result.InProgress)
            {
                connectionStatus.text = "Connecting...";
            }
            else
            {
                source.clip = DownloadHandlerAudioClip.GetContent(radioRequest);
                connectionStatus.text = "Connected!";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And a image of my scene. You can see how it's set up:
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RjWLW.png)

Comment: can you try to remove the `while` loop and let me know if this still doesn't work? I have a feeling that somehow the `while` with the `WaitForSeconds` stops the thread and that's why its not working

Comment: Why not simply `yield return radioRequest.SendWebRequest();` and forget about the debug log?

Comment: Also note that the `radioRequest.result == UnityWebRequest.Result.InProgress` should never be the case once the request has completed the download ...

Comment: @derHugo can you please just write this as an answer? (this is the best answer for this problem and I don't want to steal it :P)

Comment: Are sure actually there are not maybe two downloads running? Are you sure the logs come always from the same object? Tryrather using `Debug.Log($"Pending Request... {_op.progress}%", this);` and see if actually the same object is highlighted when clicking on the console message

Comment: I commented it out and it didn't change anything. I've also tried Unitys example shown here - https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.UnityWebRequestMultimedia.GetAudioClip.html.

However, the yield return simply waits until a response is given before code after the yield is executed. I replaced it with the .isDone check as I couldn't see the progress that way.

Comment: @amitklein well if OPs wants the progress than this wouldn't be a solution ;)

Comment: Yeah, but first we need to identify the origin of the problem, right?

Comment: @LewisDawson this might be one of these crazy shots into the dark but ... is it possible that something is respawning that object or reloading the scene .. and maybe it is only complete coincidence that the download just takes the same time to finish as the object to be reloaded for what reason ever? ^^ would be one thing you can find out using the mentioned `this` is the debug log

Comment: Oh also note btw that a **stream** is probably never finished downloading .. it buffers data .. that's maybe the reason why it seams to restart later .. I'm pretty sure this won't work at all for streams

Comment: @derHugo There is only a single Radio Manager in the scene which is all you see here
https://imgur.com/8J5cWQX and here is my current code https://imgur.com/nwmGu9u. You can see the object InstanceID is printed for each call and they are the same. I will build it to a device and see what happens :)

Comment: Would maybe this help you? (a bit of though) https://stackoverflow.com/a/55794911/7111561

Comment: Thanks for the info, I didn't know the buffering happened like that. I guess now the problem is simply the Audio is not present. Given that the web request never finishes, the source.clip is never assigned. Is that right?

Comment: @derHugo I will try and adapt it to that code in the link and report back. Cheers

Comment: Thanks for closing the thread which did not help. The other thread did not provide a solution. I get "Cannot create FMOD::Sound instance for clip "" (FMOD error: The HTTP request timed out. )" error in the console, so I don't think that is a solution. My new code:
https://imgur.com/Ehck3Aw